# List of words - TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to import a list of words to create a simple wordgame with random choice. And getting the mistake of TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface. Would appreciate suggestions on what should I change in the code.

```
# Hangman
#
# -----------------------------------
# Helper code
# List of words - TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface, Python v.3.4


import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print ("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = str.split(line)
    print ("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist

def choose_word(wordlist):
    """
    wordlist (list): list of words (strings)

    Returns a word from wordlist at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordlist)

# end of helper code
# -----------------------------------

wordlist = load_words()
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace. This will tell us what line the error occurred on.

Comment: Is there any reason you open the file with buffer 0? have you tried without this parameter?

Comment: @Kevin The traceback is the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/*****/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/python_test_LiClipse/first/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    wordlist = load_words()
  File "/*****/Documents /LiClipse Workspace/python_test_LiClipse/first/__init__.py", line 41, in load_words
    print ("Loading word list from file...")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Have you redirected sys.stdout to some file?

Comment: Your traceback says that the error occurs on line 41, but the code you've shown us has fewer than 41 lines. It seems likely to me that your actual problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown us. Please provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the traceback that you have updated in the comments -

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/*****/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/python_test_LiClipse/first/**init**.py", line 65, in  wordlist = load_words() File "/*****/Documents /LiClipse Workspace/python_test_LiClipse/first/**init**.py", line 41, in load_words print ("Loading word list from file...") TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Seems like somewhere in your code your are redirecting 'sys.stdout' to a file using -

```
sys.stdout = open('some_file','wb')
```

This should be what is causing the issue , you should open the file you are redirecting output to in text mode , not binary mode -

```
sys.stdout = open('some_file','w')
```

Though I hardly doubt you need this , if you are using terminal to run the program you can use '>' in terminal when running the program to redirect it's output to a file using - `python script.py > some_file`

Comment: Yes, true. My bad. I didn´t notice that I actually posted here a version without a first few lines where there was a command `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)` in the code. I used it trying to fix the initial issue "ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O". And @Eran was right - after I deleted the 0 argument for buffer in `open`, the list of words was imported without any problems. Thank you all.

Comment: I deleted this part with `sys.stdout` which I´ve taken from another solution for "unbuffered text" issue, and then returned 2nd argument in `open` to default.